# C# entity framework String Canonical Functions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

How to use the `Right` function in entity framework query?
I have this sql query

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + '4'), DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DateReceived, GETDATE()) % 60), 2)  
FROM mytable //RESULTS = 04
```

The `Right` function will basically add `0` infront if the passed string's length is less than 2.

Now I want to do the same thing in entity framework query:

```
var query = (from b in sovDB.myTable
select new
{
    myMinutes = Right("0"+ (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("MINUTE", b.DateReceived,  
    SqlFunctions.GetDate()) % 60),2)
}).ToList();
```

But it doesnt work, somehow the `Right` function is not supported.

Comment: Parentheses in your SQL do not look balanced.

Comment: I am not sure implicit type conversion is supported by EF yet: `"0"`(string)`+ (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("MINUTE", b.DateReceived,  SqlFunctions.GetDate()) % 60)`(int). What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same issue when converting an old stored procedure to entity. I used SqlFunctions.Replicate which did the trick and Entity Framework had no complaints!

```
var query = (from b in sovDB.myTable
select new
{
    myMinutes = SqlFunctions.Replicate("0", 2 - (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("MINUTE", b.DateReceived, GetDate()) % 60).Length) + (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("MINUTE", b.DateReceived, GetDate()) % 60)
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly convert calculated minute to string:

```
var query = (from b in sovDB.myTable
select new
{
    myMinutes = Right("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((int)(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("MINUTE", b.DateReceived, SqlFunctions.GetDate()) % 60)), 2)
}).ToList();
```